# Cost-sensitive learning in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to set up a cost-sensitive binary classification learning in TensorFlow, which would put different penalties on false positives and false negatives. Does anyone know how to create a loss function from a set of penalty weights $(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4)$ for (true positive, false positive, false negative, true negative).

I went over the standard cost functions offered, but can't figure out how to combine them to get something similar to the above.

Answer (score 4):

Following @Cauchyzhou's answer, if you have the logits, and the sparse labels as well as a cost_matrix whose shape is [L, L], where L is the number of unique labels, you can simply use the function below to calculate the loss

```
def sparse_cost_sensitive_loss (logits, labels, cost_matrix):
    batch_cost_matrix = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(cost_matrix, labels)
    eps = 1e-6
    probability = tf.clip_by_value(tf.nn.softmax(logits), eps, 1-eps)
    cost_values = tf.log(1-probability)*batch_cost_matrix
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(cost_values, axis=1))
    return loss
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of anyone who has built a cost sensitive neural network classifier but [Alejandro Correa Bahnsen](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=hzbPsTsAAAAJ&hl=en) has published academic papers for [cost sensitive logistic regression](http://albahnsen.com/files/Example-Dependent%20Cost-Sensitive%20Logistic%20Regression%20for%20Credit%20Scoring_publish.pdf) and [cost sensitive decision trees](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417415002845) and a very well documented python [cost sensitive classification library named CostCla](https://github.com/albahnsen/CostSensitiveClassification). CostCla is pretty easy to use if you are familiar with scikit-learn.

You should be able to use the [Bayes minimum risk model](http://albahnsen.com/CostSensitiveClassification/BayesMinimumRiskClassifier.html) in the library to [minimize the cost](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/roc/) of your neural network since it fits a cost model to output prediction probabilities of any classifier.

Note that CostCla is intended to work with potentially different costs for each sample. You give it a cost matrix for your training and test samples. However, you can just make all the rows in the cost matrix the same if that applies to your problem.

Here are a couple of additional academic papers on the subject:

- [The Foundations of Cost-Sensitive Learning](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2402/9028c1b280c7e62491999824853212ae148c.pdf)
- [Optimal ROC Curve    for a Combination of Classifiers](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~tygar/papers/Optimal_ROC_curve.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

cost_matrix:

```
[[0,1,100],
[1,0,1],
[1,20,0]]
```

label:

```
[1,2]
```

y*:

```
[[0,1,0],
[0,0,1]]
```

y(prediction):

```
[[0.2,0.3,0.5],
[0.1,0.2,0.7]]
```

label,cost_matrix-->cost_embedding:

```
[[1,0,1],
[1,20,0]]
```

It obvious 0.3 in [0.2,0.3,0.5] refers to right lable probility of [0,1,0], so it should not contibute to loss.

0.7 in [0.1,0.2,0.7] is the same. In other words, the pos with value 1 in y* not contibute to loss.

So I have (1-y*):

```
[[1,0,1],
[1,1,0]]
```

Then the entropy is target*log(predict) + (1-target) * log(1-predict),and value 0 in y*,should use (1-target)*log(1-predict), so I use (1-predict) said (1-y)

1-y:

```
[[0.8,*0.7*,0.5],
[0.9,0.8,*0.3*]]
```

(italic num is useless)

the custom loss is

```
[[1,0,1], [1,20,0]]   *   log([[0.8,0.7,0.5],[0.9,0.8,0.3]])    *  
[[1,0,1],[1,1,0]]
```

and you can see the (1-y*) can be drop here

so the loss is -tf.reduce_mean(cost_embedding*log(1-y))
,to make it applicable , should be:

```
-tf.reduce_mean(cost_embedding*log(tf.clip((1-y),1e-10)))
```

the demo is below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
hidden_units = 50
num_class = 3
class Model():
    def __init__(self,name_scope,is_custom):
        self.name_scope = name_scope
        self.is_custom = is_custom
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,hidden_units])
        self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None])

        self.instantiate_weights()
        self.logits = self.inference()
        self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.logits,axis=1)
        self.losses,self.train_op = self.opitmizer()

    def instantiate_weights(self):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name_scope + 'FC'):
            self.W = tf.get_variable('W',[hidden_units,num_class])
            self.b = tf.get_variable('b',[num_class])

            self.cost_matrix = tf.constant(
                np.array([[0,1,100],[1,0,100],[20,5,0]]),
                dtype = tf.float32
            )

    def inference(self):
        return tf.matmul(self.input_x,self.W) + self.b

    def opitmizer(self):
        if not self.is_custom:
            loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits\
                (labels=self.input_y,logits=self.logits)
        else:
            batch_cost_matrix = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
                self.cost_matrix,self.input_y
            )
            loss = - tf.log(1 - tf.nn.softmax(self.logits))\
                     * batch_cost_matrix

        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
        return loss,train_op

import random
batch_size = 128
norm_model = Model('norm',False)
custom_model = Model('cost',True)
split_point = int(0.9 * dataset_size)
train_set = datasets[:split_point]
test_set = datasets[split_point:]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        batch_index = random.sample(range(split_point),batch_size)
        train_batch = train_set[batch_index]
        train_labels = lables[batch_index]
        _,eval_predict,eval_loss = sess.run([norm_model.train_op,
                  norm_model.predictions,norm_model.losses],
                  feed_dict={
                      norm_model.input_x:train_batch,
                      norm_model.input_y:train_labels
        })
        _,eval_predict1,eval_loss1 = sess.run([custom_model.train_op,
                  custom_model.predictions,custom_model.losses],
                  feed_dict={
                      custom_model.input_x:train_batch,
                      custom_model.input_y:train_labels
        })
        # print '默认',eval_predict,'\n自定义',eval_predict1
        print np.sum(((eval_predict == train_labels)==True).astype(np.int)),\
            np.sum(((eval_predict1 == train_labels)==True).astype(np.int))
        if i%10 == 0:
            print  '默认测试',sess.run(norm_model.predictions,
                  feed_dict={
                      norm_model.input_x:test_set,
                      norm_model.input_y:lables[split_point:]
        })
            print  '自定义测试',sess.run(custom_model.predictions,
                  feed_dict={
                      custom_model.input_x:test_set,
                      custom_model.input_y:lables[split_point:]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is other solution where you can use any tensorflow loss and make it cost sensitive using kwarg `weights` ... note that unlike most cases here you need to use cost as '1' instead of '0' when you want to keep loss as it is ...

Some advantages of this approach are:

- it extends `tf.losses.Loss` and satisfies the `call` api
- `reduction` kwarg of the original loss remains functional and the behaviour is propagated to `CostSensitiveLoss`
- you can also pass your own extra `weights` to new loss instances. Note that internally generated weights are used by wrapped `self.loss`

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.api._v2 import keras as tk
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import losses_utils
import typing as t


class CostSensitiveLoss(tk.losses.Loss):

    def __init__(
        self,
        cost_matrix: t.List, loss: tk.losses.Loss,
    ):
        super().__init__(reduction=loss.reduction, name=loss.name)
        self.loss = loss
        self.cost_matrix = cost_matrix
        self._cost_matrix = tf.constant(cost_matrix, dtype=tf.float32)

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        config['loss'] = tk.losses.deserialize(config['loss'])
        return cls(**config)

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            'cost_matrix': self.cost_matrix,
            'loss': tk.losses.serialize(self.loss),
            'reduction': self.reduction, 'name': self.name
        }
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # if y_true is one hot encoded then get integer indices
        if y_true.ndim == 1:
            y_true_index = y_true
        elif y_true.ndim == 2:
            y_true_index = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
        else:
            raise Exception(f"`y_true.ndim` {y_true.ndim} not supported")
        
        # get cost for batch
        cost_for_batch = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self._cost_matrix, y_true_index)
        cost_for_batch *= y_pred
        cost_for_batch = tf.reduce_sum(cost_for_batch, axis=1)
        
        # get loss
        return self.loss(y_true, y_pred, cost_for_batch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for debug purpose I have kept 'none' you can
    # safely use other options like 'sum', 'auto'
    _loss = tk.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(reduction='none')
    
    # some cost matrices the first cost matrix is the case when you are
    # not using cost sensitive weights
    _cs_loss_1 = CostSensitiveLoss(
        cost_matrix=[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], ],
        loss=_loss
    )
    _cs_loss_2 = CostSensitiveLoss(
        cost_matrix=[[1, 2, 2], [4, 1, 4], [8, 8, 1], ],
        loss=_loss
    )
    _cs_loss_3 = CostSensitiveLoss(
        cost_matrix=[[1, 4, 8], [2, 1, 8], [2, 4, 1], ],
        loss=_loss
    )
    _y_true = np.asarray(
        [
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
        ]
    )
    _y_pred = np.asarray(
        [
            [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
            [0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
            [0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
            
            [0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
            [0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
            [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
            
            [0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
            [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
            [0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
        ]
    )
    print("loss ........................")
    print(_loss(_y_true, _y_pred).numpy())
    
    print("cs_loss_1 ...................")
    print(_cs_loss_1(_y_true, _y_pred).numpy())
    
    print("cs_loss_2 ...................")
    print(_cs_loss_2(_y_true, _y_pred).numpy())
    
    print("cs_loss_3 ...................")
    print(_cs_loss_3(_y_true, _y_pred).numpy())
```